# ModalBottomSheetLayout is jumping on flinging in Compose 1.4.0 and above

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I searching for possibility for turning OFF this "jumping"

https://www.veed.io/view/0f7585b4-529f-4700-8dc2-15788164fa44

I don't see it on Compose version below 1.4.0.
My code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
            ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                sheetState = sheetState,
                sheetContent = {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(200.dp),
                        text = "CONTENT"
                    )
                }
            ) {
                Button(onClick = { scope.launch { sheetState.show() } }) {
                    Text(text = "MODAL")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searching for possibility for turning OFF this "jumping feature".

PS. looks like there is an issue for that already https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/285847707, but maybe someone has a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with `Modifier.nestedScroll` in sheetContent, don't know how long it will take Google to solve this problem, so I have to solve it myself, however this is no any EdgeEffect, it seems not very good while scroll to the edge.

```
package com.lalilu.component.extension

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollSource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Velocity
import kotlin.math.abs

class BottomSheetNestedScrollInterceptor : NestedScrollConnection {
    private var arrivedBoundarySource: NestedScrollSource? = null

    override fun onPreScroll(
        available: Offset,
        source: NestedScrollSource
    ): Offset {
        // Reset the state variable
        if (source == NestedScrollSource.Drag && arrivedBoundarySource == NestedScrollSource.Fling) {
            arrivedBoundarySource = null
        }

        return super.onPreScroll(available, source)
    }

    override fun onPostScroll(
        consumed: Offset,
        available: Offset,
        source: NestedScrollSource
    ): Offset {
        // The sub-layout can't consume completely,
        // which means that the boundary has been reached.
        if (arrivedBoundarySource == null && abs(available.y) > 0) {
            arrivedBoundarySource = source
        }

        // Decide whether to consume according to the sub-layout
        // consumption when reaching the boundary.
        if (arrivedBoundarySource == NestedScrollSource.Fling) {
            return available
        }

        return Offset.Zero
    }

    override suspend fun onPostFling(
        consumed: Velocity,
        available: Velocity
    ): Velocity {
        arrivedBoundarySource = null
        return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberBottomSheetNestedScrollInterceptor(): BottomSheetNestedScrollInterceptor {
    return remember { BottomSheetNestedScrollInterceptor() }
}
```